# "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type nvarchar."

Tags: sql, sql-server, overflow, common-table-expression, sqldatatypes

I'm trying to do a comparison of data between 2 tables, where I need to join multiple columns as a composite key to get a unique identifier. I'm using a CTE and the code I have is:

```
WITH SuburbDataTest AS (
  SELECT *
    ,  CAST(Address AS NVARCHAR(100))+' ' +CAST(LivingAddress AS NVARCHAR(2))
    + ' ' + CAST(StartDate AS NVARCHAR(11))+ ' ' +CAST(AddressTypeId AS NVARCHAR(1))
    + ' ' +CAST(SuburbId AS NVARCHAR(1))AS SuburbDataTestColumn
  FROM [mig].[ConsumerAddressMigration]
  WHERE SuburbId is NOT NULL
)
SELECT *
FROM SuburbDataTest staging
WHERE SuburbDataTestColumn IN (
  SELECT Address+' ' +CAST(LivingAddress AS NVARCHAR(2))+ ' '+CAST(StartDate AS NVARCHAR(11))
    + ' ' +CAST(AddressTypeId AS NVARCHAR(1))+ ' ' +CAST(SuburbId AS NVARCHAR(1)) AS SuburbDataTestColumn
  FROM [dbo].[tblConsumerAddress]
)
```

Unfortunately I'm getting

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type nvarchar.

Any ideas?

Comment: can we see the schema of [mig].[ConsumerAddressMigration] and that of [dbo].[tblConsumerAddress]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens when you are converting a number to a string -- and the string is not big enough.  I would guess this is the problem:

```
CAST(SuburbId AS NVARCHAR(1))
```

If `SuburbId` is a number larger than 9, then this will generate an error.  Or, for that matter if the value is negative you'll get the same error as well.

Comment: Duh! I was so blind! Really grateful @Gordon Linoff!